# R: Set next row to NA in group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to set the next row  i+1 in the same column to NA if there is already an NA in row i and then do this by groups. Here is my attempt:

```
dfeg <- tibble(id = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)),
               x = c(1, 2, NA, NA, 3, 5, 6, NA, NA, 7))

setNextrowtoNA <- function(x){
  
  for (j in 1:length(x)){
    
    if(is.na(x[j])){x[j+1] <- NA}
    
  }
}

dfeg <- dfeg %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(y = setNextrowtoNA(x))
```

However my attempt doesn't create the column y that am looking for. Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

EDIT: In my actual data I have multiple values in a row that need to be set to NA, for example my data is more like this:

```
dfeg <- tibble(id = c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 6)),
                   x = c(1, 2, NA, NA, 3, 4, 15, 16, NA, NA, 17, 18))
```

And need to create a column like this:

```
y = c(1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15, 16, NA, NA, NA, NA)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT 2:

I figured it out on my own, this seems to work:

```
dfeg <- tibble(id = c(rep("A", 6), rep("B", 6)),
               x = c(1, 2, NA, NA, 3, 4,  15, 16, NA, NA, 17, 18))

setNextrowtoNA <- function(x){
  
  for (j in 1:(length(x))){
    
    if(is.na(x[j]))
    {
      x[j+1] <- NA
      }
    lengthofx <- length(x)
    x <- x[-lengthofx]
    print(x[j])
  }
  return(x)
}

dfeg <- dfeg %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(y = NA,
                                         y = setNextrowtoNA(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cumany`:

```r
library(dplyr)
dfeg %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(y = ifelse(cumany(is.na(x)), NA, x))

   id        x     y
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A         1     1
 2 A         2     2
 3 A        NA    NA
 4 A        NA    NA
 5 A         3    NA
 6 A         4    NA
 7 B        15    15
 8 B        16    16
 9 B        NA    NA
10 B        NA    NA
11 B        17    NA
12 B        18    NA
```

---

Previous answer:

Use an `ifelse` statement with `lag`:

```r
library(dplyr)
dfeg %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(y = ifelse(is.na(lag(x, default = 0)), NA, x))
```

Comment: wow thanks! Just wondering, do you know what was up with my own approach? It would be great to know where I went wrong there. :)

Comment: I'd suggest you to test your function with a single vector (e.g. dfeg$x). When doing that, you can see that one problem is that your function creates a vector of size n+1, because of the j+1. I would recommend using j-1 and j. (But this may not be enough to make it work).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't acutally consider the case where there are more than one values that need to be set NA, I edited my post to give an example. Your answer was totally correct given my original question, but do you know how to adapt it to the edit? Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Yes I'd use `cumany` in that case. see edit